# docker exec : vpn: checking ip address shows the ISP ip address

Tags: docker, containers, vpn

I have a docker container which runs a vpn

Inside the docker i run `curl ipinfo.io/$(curl ifconfig.me)` i get the vpn ip and location

```
docker exec -it vpnmy /bin/bash
[root@158983fe36a0 /]# curl ipinfo.io/$(curl ifconfig.me)
  "ip": "xxx.xxx.x.xx",
  "city": "New York City",
  "region": "New York",
  "country": "US",
```

the above the vpn location i selected and its showing as intended. Means vpn is working

where as when i try

```
$ docker exec -it vpnmy curl ipinfo.io/$(curl ifconfig.me)
  "ip": "xxx.xxx.x.xx",
  "city": "current city",
  "region": "current region",
  "country": "current country",
```

It shows my Internet service providers ip global details

But i want to keep checking without need to first get into bash prompt and run curl

How can i do this

Comment: You can issue the command using bash command flag docker exec -it /bin/bash -c “curl ipinfo.io/$(curl ifconfig.me)” keep in mind that this will trigger the command I don’t think the output would be visible. Though, if you wanted to review the output just generate a file like so docker exec -it /bash/bash -c “curl ipinfo.io/$(curl ifconfig.me) >> tee -a result.txt it simply appends the command results in a file called result that are many ways to do it this would be just one example

Comment: `docker exec -it vpmy /bin/bash -c "curl ipinfo.io/$(curl ifconfig.me)"` it outputs the result, but not the vpn ip but my isp ip

Comment: From what I understand. When you create a container it’s network is bridged with your host system. I believe you need to create a docker-machine ip and the setup a docker network  with custom dns settings within your docker-compose file.

Answer (score 0):

When you run

```sh
docker exec -it vpnmy curl ipinfo.io/$(curl ifconfig.me)
```

first your local shell outside of Docker runs the embedded `curl` command; then it launches a container running the outer `curl` command with the IP address from the host embedded in the URL.

```sh
# after the _host_ does command substitution, this runs
docker exec -it vpnmy curl ip-info.io/10.20.30.40
# with the host's IP address
```

Since you want that expansion to run inside the container, you need the `docker exec` command to be a shell, and you need to pass the command to it in *single* quotes to prevent the host from running the command.  (A similar example in comments uses double quotes, which does not prevent this.)

```sh
# note `sh -c` wrapper and single quotes
docker exec -it vpnmy sh -c 'curl ipinfo.io/$(curl ifconfig.me)'
```

If the `ipinfo.io` server doesn't care where the request is coming from, another option is to run the outer `curl` command on the host and the inner one in the container.  For the command you show switching layers like this could be a little confusing, but it could be easier to run if you need to do more processing in the script.

```sh
curl ipinfo.io/$(docker exec vpnmy curl ifconfig.me)
```

```sh
VPN_IP=$(docker exec vpnmy curl ifconfig.me)
curl "ipinfo.io/$VPN_IP"
```